# What's the Pandas way to write `if()` conditional between two `timeseries` columns?

Tags: pandas, time-series

My naive approach to Pandas `Series` needs some pointers. I have **one Pandas DataFrame** with **two joined tables**. The left table had `timestamp` with title `Time1` and the right had `Time2`; My new DataFrame has both.

At this step I'm comparing the two `datetime` columns using helper functions `g()` and `f()`:

```
df['date_error'] = g(df['Time1'], df['Time2'])
```

The working helper function `g()` compares two `datetime` values:

```
def g(newer,older):
    value = newer > older
    return value
```

This gives me a column `(True,False)` values. When I use the conditional in the helper function `f()`, I get an error because `newer` and `older` are Pandas `Series`:

```
def f(newer,older):
    if newer > older:
        delta = (newer - older) 
    else :
        # arbitrairly large value to maintain col dtype
        delta = datetime.timedelta(minutes=1000)
    return delta
```

Ok. Fine. I know I'm not unpacking the Pandas Series correctly, because I can get this to work with the following monstrosity:

```
def f(newer,older):
    delta = []
    for (k,v),(k2,v2) in zip(newer.iteritems(), older.iteritems()):
        if v > v2 :
            delta.append(v - v2) 
        else :
            # arbitrairly large value to maintain col dtype
            delta.append(datetime.timedelta(minutes=1000))

    return pd.Series(delta)
```

What's the Pandas way a conditional between two DataFrame columns?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually `where` is the pandas equivalent of if:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['1/1/01 11:00', '1/1/01 12:00'], 
                   ['1/1/01 14:00', '1/1/01 13:00']],                  
                       columns = ['Time1', 'Time2']
                  ).apply(pd.to_datetime)

(df.Time1 - df.Time2).where(df.Time1 > df.Time2)

0        NaT
1   01:00:00
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

If you don't want nulls in this column you could call `fillna(1000)` afterwards, however note that this datatype supports a null value `NaT` (not a time).